# spring-data-envers -2.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-envers

Right now we are using 0.3.0.RELEASE to get the revision data and noticed that the revisions are fetched in ascending order. 
the existing code

```
@EnableJpaRepositories( value = "org.xxx.xxx.xxx.repository", repositoryFactoryBeanClass = RevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class )
@EnableJpaAuditing( auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware" )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
.......
}

public class RevisionRepositoryFactoryBean extends EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean {

    public RevisionRepositoryFactoryBean() {
        setRevisionEntityClass( Revision.class );
    }

}
```

Found that the newer version 2.0.0.RELEASE has functionality to sort based on sort in pageable object. So wanted to use 2.0.0.RELEASE.

the following is the modifications

```
public class RevisionRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends RevisionRepository<S, ID, N>, S, ID extends Serializable, N extends Number & Comparable<N>> extends EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID,N> {

    public RevisionRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
        setRevisionEntityClass( Revision.class );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

but did not work...
compile error in DatabaseConfiguration file

No constructor with 0 arguments defined in class 
 'org.xxx.xxx.xxx.config.RevisionRepositoryFactoryBean'

Do anyone has an example how to use spring-data-envers -2.0.0.RELEASE in spring boot application.
Thanks
Srini

Comment: How have you specified the version? You need to make sure you are getting the matching version of the other Spring Data modules as well (spring-data-commons, spring-data-jpa)